# Why I have duplicate month number

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, count

I dont understand, why the result of this query displays duplicate month with different count number of sumbmission:

```
 [![SELECT      CAST(B.YearNum as varchar(10))+ ' Submitted'  as Type,
                1 as OrderNum,
                COUNT( ControlNo) Count,
                b.YearNum, b.MonthNum
    FROM        tblCalendar b 
                    LEFT JOIN   ClearanceReportMetrics a  ON b.MonthNum = MONTH(a.EffectiveDate) AND b.YearNum=YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
                    AND CompanyLine = 'Plaza Insurance Company' AND Underwriter <> 'Batcheller, Jerry'
    WHERE       YEAR(EffectiveDate) IN (2016, 2015,2014)
    GROUP BY    b.YearNum, b.MonthNum, Type
    order by b.YearNum, b.MonthNum][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably on of the source tables has `type` column .

```
select year + 1 as type, count(*)
from (
      values 
        (1, 2014, 1)
      , (2, 2014, 2)
    ) t (id,year, type)
group by year, type
```

Comment: OMG!!! You are so right!!! How I could not notice that! 
Serg, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!